# Concatenar hierarquia de lista

Tags: php

Tenho este cenário de html no php.

```
<ul id="titulo1"></ul>
  <ul id="capitulo1"></ul> 
    <ul id="artigo1"></ul>
    <ul id="artigo2"></ul>

<ul id="titulo2"></ul>
   <ul id="artigo1"></ul>
```

Gostaria de adicionar a hierarquia nas classes, para ficar assim

```
<ul id="titulo1"></ul>
  <ul id="titulo1_capitulo1"></ul> 
    <ul id="titulo1_capitulo1_artigo1"></ul>
    <ul id="titulo1_capitulo1_artigo2"></ul>

<ul id="titulo2"></ul>
   <ul id="titulo2_artigo1"></ul>
```

Comment: e o que você já tentou?

Comment: Por que você está usando ULs? neste caso??? não entendi. Não seria melhor usar h1, h2, h3, h4 e h5? Este já são, por si só, títulos hierárquicos. inclusive entendíveis semanticamente e recomendados pelo W3C....

Comment: Porque os artigos normalmente são divididos em 3 artes, cabeça, incisos e paragráfos, mas, às vezes, nos incisos subitens também.
E no ul pode-se aninhar outra ul dentro dela, o que não acontece com os headers.
Mas ainda não sou fera na programação, se eu estiver errado e houver outro jeito mais inteligente de fazer, gostaria de saber.

Comment: relacionado http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/82934/13561