# CSS - como fazer numeração de todos os níveis em listas aninhadas

Tags: css

Como fazer a numeração de lista aninhada incluir os números dos elementos pais (todos os níveis), utilizando somente CSS?

Por padrão as listas só exibem a numeração de um nível:

```html
<ol>
  <li>item
    <ol>
      <li>item
        <ol>
          <li>item</li>
          <li>item</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li>item</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>item
    <ol>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

O resultado esperado é assim:

```
1. item
  1.1. item
    1.1.1. item
    1.1.2. item
  1.2. item
2. item
  2.1. item
  2.2. item
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para fazer isso é necessário utilizar a função `counters()` da propriedade `content` dentro de pseudo-elemento CSS `::before` de cada item da lista. Fonte: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Counters.

Observação 1: Só é possível utilizar um tipo de numeração (e.g. decimais, romanos, letras) para todos os níveis, não sendo possível misturar dois ou mais tipos.

Observação 2: Ao selecionar e copiar a lista os números não serão copiados, somente os textos.

```css
ol {
  /* zera contador para cada lista */
  counter-reset: item;
  /* remove estilo de lista padrão */
  list-style-type: none;
}
li::before {
  /* incrementa só o contador da lista atual */
  counter-increment: item;
  /* adiciona o valor de todos os contadores pai
  separados pelo segundo parâmetro */
  content: counters(item,'.') '. ';
  /* para suporte a IE < 8 não pode haver espaço entre os argumentos */
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>item
    <ol>
      <li>item
        <ol>
          <li>item</li>
          <li>item</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li>item</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>item
    <ol>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: essa é nova pra mim! nem sabia que tinha como fazer!